# Appending a text to a JTextArea after Using a DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing

I am a having problem with appending a text to a JTextArea after Using a DocumentFilter,
I need to append a string on the JTextArea after the text has been uploaded from a file and also return a string from a JTextArea of another JFrame to the specified JTextArea

Everything worked perfectly when I didn't use the DocumentFilter.FilterBypass until when I added it. It still works a little but only when comma(,) or space(" ") isn't added. Which is not to the specification I was given.

How can I solve this? Or is there any algorithm or implementation that doesn't give this problem?

This is the insertString code to filter the length, and only allow space and comma

```
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    // if (string == null || string.trim().equals("") || string.equals(","))
    // {
    // return;
    // }

    if (isNumeric(string)) {
        // if (this.length > 0 && fb.getDocument().getLength() +
        // string.length()
        // > this.length) {
        // return;
        // }
        if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + string.length() > this.length || string.trim().equals("") || string.equals(",")) {
            this.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
        // if (string == null || string.trim().equals("") ||
        // string.equals(",")) {
        // return;
        // }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
    else if (string == null || string.trim().equals("") || string.equals(",")) {
        super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }

}

@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    if (isNumeric(text)) {
        if (this.length > 0 && fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() > this.length) {
            return;
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attrs);
    }
}

/**
 * This method tests whether given text can be represented as number. This
 * method can be enhanced further for specific needs.
 * 
 * @param text
 *            Input text.
 * @return {@code true} if given string can be converted to number;
 *         otherwise returns {@code false}.
 */
private boolean isNumeric(String text) {
    if (text == null || text.trim().equals("") || text.equals(",")) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount < text.length(); iCount++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(iCount))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The other two functions (append from file & append from a different frame) I want to implement innocently by just appending their string values to the JTextArea that is filtered using this. But is being refused by super.insertString(.....)

Comment: What code are you using at the moment that is not working? Mind posting it?

Comment: No problem, But its long though. Have to attach the codes of the two frames

Comment: maybe just the snippet where you are trying to add the "," and " "?

Comment: But the specification I was given mandates me to add them. I cant do away with them

Comment: How can I get around it. The javadoc specific at all on doing that

Comment: Its working just fine with dat

Comment: This is the scenerio. Its more like a wizard, If you click next it goes to the next frame and shows everthing just fine. But if you click back other fields show even another filtered using document filter(but with no comma or space allowed except this one. It just shows a blank space

Comment: so when going back the textarea is keeping the information from the previous frame? Or is the frame completely empty?

Comment: Its just the textArea that needs information that is empty, other info are available in the frame

Comment: should your text.trim = (" ") not ("")? theres no space in your code its a clear?

Comment: If it works the first time just perform the action you used when you first loaded the frame again whenever you call the action that sends you back a frame? I think I've confused myself haha

Comment: If by any chance you have solved this issue I am curious and theres a nice chunk of rep awaiting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really got your question. If you want to have a filter where you can paste complete numbers or "," and whitespace (end or beginning or entered) but cannot paste any other text you can just change your isNumeric function:

```
private boolean isNumeric(String text) {
   text = text.trim();
   if(",".equals(text)) return true;
   ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
   java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parse(text, position);
   return position.getIndex() == text.length();
}
```

Comment: you don't need the other checks in your insertString method in this case

Comment: Thanks for the post, I have been curious about this post for the last week, and hopefully this is an answer. So with only an hour left I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get the carat location before appending the text. I am not to familiar with DocumentFilters and i am assuming that the `this.append("stringzzz")` method is not available?

It seems there is something wrong with yout offset. You may need to set it up to get a position first, something like below. [InsertString() Doc (OffSet)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.FilterBypass.html)

As for getting the carat position you could do something like `TextPane.getCaretPosition(),` and pass that in. Instead of using the FilterByPass?

Something like(as suggested in my link)

```
this.insertString(TextArea.getCaretPosition(), yourString, null);
```

Here is a link that may be of some help.

[Inserting Text without FilterByPass](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/16385)

Let me know if I am way off :)

Comment: -1, Your comments about the caret position is not related to the problem. A Document (or Model) knows nothing about the Swing component (the view). Remember a Model can be shared by multiple components. A DocumentFilter is used to edit the text before it is inserted into the Document. If the OPs code isn't working its because the logic in the DocumentFilter is wrong.

Comment: @camickr Makes sense he had me confused when he said it worked but only when not using specific characters, and then said it worked as long as he didn't backtrack to it. So it led me to believe it was something else.

Comment: @camickr, Do you mind, if i paste the code for the logic of the documentfilter for you to take a look at. Read the javadoc some more, and it seems the problem isn't from the documentfilter itself, but the AbstractDocument class.